# Why does WScript work when I run my script from the desktop, but not when run as part of Setup.exe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vbscript, installshield, wsh

I've been working on this issue for about 6 hours now and feel like I'm getting nowhere.  I have a vbscript to write to the windows registry that I want to use during the installation of a .net Visual Studio program.  It writes to the Local Machine part of the registry, so permissions have to be edited to accomplish that.  The code in question is as follows:

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
        , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

The code works perfectly when I just run the script from my desktop, and does exactly what I need it to do.  But when I run the setup.exe that includes the script (even if I run setup.exe from my desktop), I get an Object Required error from the WScript code above.  I need to know either 1) why I am getting this error and how to allow access to the WScript object, or if that is impossible 2) how to give my script the proper admin privileges required to write to the Local Machine Registry without using WScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this script as a VBScript custom action, then Windows Installer uses a custom VB script host. Unlike wscript.exe and cscript.exe, this host does not provide the `WScript` object, so any references to it will fail. You could choose to launch it as an EXE action via wscript.exe instead. I would not recommend this, at least not without reading my third paragraph.

Also, as a general recommendation, you should avoid elevating within a custom action, as doing so leads to the potential of multiple UAC prompts during a single installation. So to write to per-machine areas of the registry you should prefer using the Registry view, and thus entries in the Registry table. If you need custom values, note that you can specify property references in the view/table, and they will be evaluated when writing the values.

If you absolutely need to write to the registry through a custom action, consider carefully the rollback scenarios, and prefer to use an action that is "deferred in system context," as this kind of custom action will have access to administrative privileges if the installation is per-machine. Note that deferred custom actions do not have access to most properties.